# Spring - jdbcTemplate - DataAccessException

Tags: java, sql, spring, sqlexception

My goal is to analyze SQL exceptions in our application and according to the type of the exception, decide whether to retry the SQL or abort. For example if it is a connection error (network unreachable), I would like to retry since it could succeed sometime in the future. However if it is an error due to a "constraintViolation", there is no need to retry since it will fail again.
I read about TransientDataAccessException and NonTransientDataAccessException and I thought it would fit well. I just would do

```
try{
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql,...);
} catch (DataAccessException){
    if(e instanceof NonTransientDataAccessException) {
        logger.error("No need to retry, we will get the same exception " + e);  
    } else if(e instanceof TransientDataAccessException){       
        logger.error("Transient Exception - we will retry " + e);
    }
}
```

It worked fine for a constraint violation however when I went on disconnecting the network temporarily, I got another type of exception: CannotCreateTransactionException which does not inherit from DataAccessException. So I think it kind of break all this nice idea of transient/non transient data access exceptions. What do you think?
Is there a better way to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to use `spring-retry` which supports this with some configuration? Also a transaction has not perse anything to do with data, could also be messaging or a transactional filesystem. As such it doesn't extend `DataAccessException`.

Comment: I was not aware of spring-retry. I will have a look at this. I understand that transaction has nothing to do with data. I thought I could use the fact that those exceptions are classified into transient/non-transient but it seems we cannot rely on it. Especially that i also got an DataAccessResourceFailureException when disconnecting the network. I would expect it to be a transient exception and not a non-transient one! anyway I will get back to you regarding spring-retry. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Deinum I used spring-retry and it meets my requirements. Syntax is a bit verbose especially that I have many calls that I need to wrap. But I will couple it with AOP: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-retry-ways-integrate in order to make it lighter. Thanks again. Please post it as an answer and i will vote.